# Hierarchical regression with partially nested variables

Tags: multilevel-analysis, mixed-model

I would like to do a logistic regression of vaccination coverage of, for example, $HPV$. Let's assume that we have 50 states ($S$). 30 states have an urban part and a country part (urbanity variable $U$). The other 20 have only a country area. 10 of the states have population areas where individuals speaks only Spanish and other areas only English ($L$). The linguistic region correlates only slightly with urbanity. For example:

$S$: 1,.., 50;
$U$: urban/country;
$L$: English/Spanish.

- S(1)-U(urban)-L(english)
- S(1)-U(country)-L(english)
- S(1)-U(urban)-L(spanish)
- S(1)-U(country)-L(spanish)
- S(2)-U(urban)-L(english)
- S(2)-U(urban)-L(spanish)
- S(3)-U(urban)-L(english)
- S(3)-U(country)-L(english)
- S(4)-U(urban)-L(english)
- S(4)-U(country)-L(spanish)

...

where the number indicate a state.

The situation is that $U$ is nested in $S$ but not each $S$ has both levels of $U$. This is also the case for the linguistic variable. If $U$ would be nested completely in $S$ and $L$ completely in $S$, the model would look like (in R-terminology for lmer): `y ~ (1|S) +(1|S:U) + (1|S:L)` where $y$: 0/1 vaccinated

Is it possible to estimate odds ratio using this model even if variables $U$ and $L$ are not completely nested?
Or Should be used another model, for example:
`y ~ (1|S) + U + L` where`(1|S)` is random variable and `U` and `L` are fixed variables.

With fixed levels $U$ and $L$ the nesting character would be lost and the variables would be characterstics of the individuals,that is, the aggregation of individuals would not be considered.
Problems which arise using fixed variables: would give significant results or narrow CI due to the high number of individuals.
I would be very happy if someone could give me some hints how to cope with partially nested variables.

Comment: `S:L` and `S:U` will form a new random effect each; then your approach treats them as crossed. You would have no problem with them not being completely nested within themselves. As for you "another model", as you correctly say: it is a matter experimental design what to do.

Comment: @user11852: thanks very much for the response (and formatting). Intuitively I thought that it shouldn't cause a problem. What will cause for me a problem is that the odds ratio won't become significant as in the fixed model (fixed U and L). This may be due to the low number of levels (only 2) which are used for the estimation of the standard deviation. In mixed effect literature (I will deliver the source later) I read that there must have at least 5 levels. But there was no statement in case of lower number of levels. The conflict is: design would be appropriate but there is too few levels.

Comment: `L` and `U` are inappropriate for random effects; `S:L` and `S:U` are fine. Using `S` and `L` as fixed effects is OK.